# Caseless PC - should I be concerned about incoming EMI

Tags: emc

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/352489/why-is-a-caseless-pc-not-an-emi-problem?noredirect=1&lq=1). I have built a custom PC case that is essentially cardboard. Are the components likely immune to ambient EMI or do they build them under the assumption that a quality case will attenuate such signals.

I am new to EE SE (though I foresee many future interactions as I plan to enter the field).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That question is asking about the PC generating EMI and interfering with other equipment, which is a different problem. The PC itself isn't going to care about ambient EMI since its own emissions are likely very large relative to its surroundings.

Comment: I think you are right about EMI from similar devices. However,  there is research that reports EMI from natural sources can flip bits. Recent research found that in the field hard faults are more likely to blame then soft failures. http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~bianca/papers/sigmetrics09.pdf

Comment: I'll mark as answered, though I was hoping for a more authoritative answer.

Comment: Though your answer is basically correct, the emphasis is wrong. The PC doesn't care about typical ambient EMI, period. BTW, its own emissions are very large, and keeping those down is why the metal case, and ferrite cylinders on the leads, are usually found.

Comment: I often operate PCs with the case top/sides off and hard drives dangling outside by their cables, or even just the bare motherboard and other bits strewn across the bench. Never had any problems due to EMI. I think any risk is more theoretical than practical (I'd be more worried about static discharge).